# My code keeps putting out http500 error. Cannot find any problems

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

I am building this code to change the password of a simple login system (I know it isn't verry secure) Now I am coding the following bit of code but when I execute it it puts out an HTTP 500 error, so I checked it for errors but could not find any. I entered it in a PHP validator. Allso with no relult. Does any of you maybe know what I am not seeing right now?

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_POST['updatepassword'])) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'creatalo_mika', 'Temppass100_', 'creatalo_lscdb') or die("verbinding error");
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE username='$user'") or die("selection error");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $dbpass = $row['password'];
    $newpass = $_POST['password'];
    $pass = $_POST['passwordold'];
    $passen = md5(md5('dsgf'.$pass.'sadf'));
    if ($passen == $dbpass) {
        $newpass = md5(md5('dsgf'.$newpass.'sadf'));

        $sql->query("UPDATE users_table SET password='$newpass' WHERE username='$user'") or die($mysqli->error);
        header("location: ../index.php ") or die($mysqli->error);
    } else {
        header("location: ../index.php#notgood ") or die($mysqli->error);
    }
}
```

Comment: i know it isn't secure. but i am still experimenting with php login systems, after i can make the basic stuf i ll make a more advanced system.

Comment: You are just creating more trouble for yourself. Prepared statements are not difficult and `password_hash` is easier than MD5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems with [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1839439), [password hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439), and you are completely [confused about `die($mysqli->error)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439) for which I do not blame you. I fixed your problems to show you how the code should look like more or less, but if you are creating authentication system you really should read more about security first.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['updatepassword'])) {
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'creatalo_mika', 'Temppass100_', 'creatalo_lscdb');

    $user = $_POST['username'];

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

    if (password_verify($_POST['passwordold'], $row['password'])) {
        $newpass = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users_table SET password=? WHERE username=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $newpass, $user);
        $stmt->execute();
        exit(header("location: ../index.php "));
    } else {
        exit(header("location: ../index.php#notgood "));
    }
}
```

Most importantly enable error reporting:
[How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: thanks, i think its a better lession for me to learn making a login system correctly then one with poor security. i ll try looking into making a new one!